# How to identify identical groups using pandas.groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to use pandas to identify sub-sections of a dataframe which are identical. So, for example, if I have a dataframe like:

```
   id  A  B 
0   1  1  2
1   1  2  3
2   1  5  6
3   2  1  2
4   2  2  3
5   2  5  6
6   3  8  9
7   3  4  0
8   3  9  7
```

I want to group by ID, so Rows 0 - 2 would form Group 1, Rows 3 - 5 would form Group 2, and Rows 6 - 8 would form Group 3. I know I can use `pd.groupby()` to group rows by ID.  In the case here, Group 2 is a repetition of Group 1 (Columns A and B are identical in both)

What I then want to do is to remove repeated groups, so in this case I would want to remove the second group. My final dataframe would then look like:

```
   id  A  B 
0   1  1  2
1   1  2  3
2   1  5  6
6   3  8  9
7   3  4  0
8   3  9  7
```

Every column in the duplicate groups is the same, except for the ID which is different for each group.  I only want to remove a group if it is **identical for every row in the group**. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using a helper column and [`pd.Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html).

The idea is to first create a mapping from `id` to a tuple of values representing all rows for that `id`. Then drop duplicates and extract the index of the remainder.

```
df['C'] = list(zip(df['A'], df['B']))

s = df.groupby('id')['C'].apply(tuple)\
      .drop_duplicates().index

res = df.loc[df['id'].isin(s), ['id', 'A', 'B']]

print(res)

   id  A  B
0   1  1  2
1   1  2  3
2   1  5  6
6   3  8  9
7   3  4  0
8   3  9  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `pd.crosstab`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.id,[df.A,df.B]).drop_duplicates().unstack()
s[s!=0].reset_index().drop(0,1)
Out[128]: 
   A  B  id
0  1  2   1
1  2  3   1
2  4  0   3
3  5  6   1
4  8  9   3
5  9  7   3
```

Comment: In case somebody else stumbles upon this 5 years later, `drop(0,1)` now requires to be `drop(0, axis=1)` as axis was turned into a keyword only argument.